# React jsx not adding event listener to the element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I have a react-redux app which requires a part which is conditional.
i.e. it can either be a div with a certain className or a div with the same className and an onClick handler which fires an action. so I created a function which returns jsx according to the above conditions.
Now the problem is that the onClick is not being added to the props as I expected but className is working fine.

```
class someClass {
    renderSomething(){
         return <div className="someClass" onClick={() => 
    this.props.someAction()}>Something</div>
}
   render(){
        {this.renderSomething()}
   } 
}
```

What I expected it to be

```
<div className="someclass" onClick={() => this.props.someAction()}>Something</div>
```

What Rect dev tools show

```
<div className="someclass">Something</div>
```

Don't know where I went wrong.

Edit 1: The function was mistakenly written outside the class.

Comment: `onClass=()=>`??? Is this a typo?

Comment: Your "Minimal, complete and verifiable example" isn't complete neither verifiable (`renderSomething` should be a method in the class component `someClass` that should extend `React.Component`, there's no conditionnal rendering as you talk about, some typos...)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. In your `renderSomething()` method, you should have the following:

```
renderSomething() {
  return (
    <div className="someclass" onClick={this.props.someAction}>Something</div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT:** Now I saw that `renderSomething` was not a part of class from it was called from. In order to keep reference to `this`, you have to move it inside of your class, hence make it class method. 
If you wish to add an argument to `someAction` function, I suggest you add a event handler to your React component, and then assign it to a onClick. Using arrow function in render method causes creation of a new function in memory every time component re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
class someClass {
    renderSomething(){
        return <div className="someClass" onClick={() => this.props.someAction()}>Something</div>
    }   

    render(){
        {this.renderSomething()}
    } 
}
```

In your original example, `renderSomething` wasn't a part of `someClass` -- so calling `this.renderSomething()` would have thrown a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but i think

```
render(){
     return {this.renderSomething()}
}
```

Is the way to go. Let me know if `render(){this.renderSomething()}` works.